# How to stop merging a github branch if it does not have all commits

Tags: git, github

Lets say that we have a github project with only 2 files in the master branch, file1.txt and file2.txt.

master

- file1.txt
- file2.txt

a new branch is created from master, change-file1 branch, in this branch file1.txt is getting changed

change-file1

- file1.txt (this file is edited)
- file2.txt (no changes)

another new branch is created from master, change-file2, in this branch only file2.txt is getting changed

change-file2

- file1.txt (no changes)
- file2.txt (this file is edited)

Now, 2 pull requests are created, from change-file1 to master, and from change-file2 to master.

github will allow to merge these pull requests without showing any conflicts (i.e. i can merge change-file1 then change-file2).

How can i stop github from accepting the merge if a branch does not have the latest commits from the master branch, (i.e. if change-file1 branch was merged first, github would prevent me from merging change-file2 branch because it does not have all the master commits)?

If i cannot do that from github, what is the best git command to make sure that a branch has all the commits from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Github’s ‘required status checks’, part of the branch protection feature:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-required-status-checks

These checks allow you to require all pull requests are up to date with the master branch, which you can do through the UI.